# Server firewall issue

Tags: linux, centos, firewall

today suddenly my website did not come up
after i contacted to my provider they told me you should type:
service iptables stop
command at your SSH,the thing is my SSH does not establish as always so i figured out i should use the temporary session which i have created at my VPS panel
this one will working on 1349 as port
so when i try to connect with the session login information after i input password the putty begins to show a huge amount of commands like these:

```
.55.226.255 LEN=160 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=14318 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=140
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:c0:f6:90:08:00 SRC=185.55.226.183 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=102
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:4c:5e:0c:fd:da:5a:08:00 SRC=192.168.10.1 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=134 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=114
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:43:1a:eb:08:00 SRC=185.55.226.153 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=160 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=24300 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=140
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:43:1a:eb:08:00 SRC=185.55.226.153 DST=185.55.226.255 LEN=160 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=14319 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=140
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:69:6b:a0:08:00 SRC=185.55.226.180 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=117 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=97
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:43:1a:eb:08:00 SRC=185.55.226.153 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=160 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=24301 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=140
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:43:1a:eb:08:00 SRC=185.55.226.153 DST=185.55.226.255 LEN=160 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=14320 PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=140
Firewall: UDP_IN Blocked IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:16:3e:c0:f6:90:08:00 SRC=185.55.226.183 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=122 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=5678 DPT=5678 LEN=102
```

which never seems to be finished!
how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kernel sending information about iptables blocking packets. Responsible for the output on the command line is the system logger. Since you haven't told us witch distribution is installed on your system, I can only guess how to stop the logger:

```
service syslog stop
service syslog-ng stop
service rsyslog stop
```

Comment: thanks,but how can i input command?because this logs continue and seems not stopping! until out of memory warning!

Comment: Well, you are already logged in, therefore just type the commands, although the system is filling the lines. From my experience, the system will only execute what you have typed, even if it interrupted by the messages.

Comment: by chance do you know why thas happened?

Comment: another question is ,is this safe to run the command:service iptables stop and chkconfig iptables off                                                                             i mean foy future.... ,i noticee i had: ConfigServer Security & Firewall - csf v9.14 at my direct Admin panel is that enough?

Comment: Well, I guess csf is nothing else than a frontend for the firewall settings which finally are based on iptables. And that means, that is it propably not a good idea. If your not familiar with the linux command line, better use a giu like csf. The flooding of the command line was cause be some setting of you syslog daemon. By the way, which of my syslog commands was the successful one? I may than be able to tell you what to change in the configuration, so that you can start the system logging again.

Comment: Many thanks for u r reply,these command worked:service rsyslog stop ihave many many message at DA like these :""Brute-Force Attack detected in service log from IP(s) 89.248.169.36"" every day,or like this one:""Brute-Force Attack detected in service log on User(s) root"" im not sure how should set the setting of "ConfigServer Security & Firewall - csf v9.14 "in DA panel.thanks